# SQL query, am I missing something?

Tags: sql

In SQL, given [this dataset](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/587c7b/17)

When I try this query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NAME= 'Bob'
```

it provides the results but when I try this, it doesn't work but it also doesn't give any error

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NAME= 'Bob' AND NAME= 'John';
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

edited:

Given the previous dataset

Find any two words appearing anywhere in the message of the dataset 
table that occur individually in more than 4 message but 
never together in the same message?

Comment: Think about what you are writing there: "*return all rows from table1 where the column `name` has the value `'Bob'` **and** the value `'John'` **at the same time***" - a column can only have a *single* value

Comment: ye, I needed to use OR, silly mistake

Comment: How can a value be at the same time x and y?

Comment: Could you show an example of the second question, please?

Comment: @Seeker: I had answered both of your questions correctly and you had accepted my answer. Now, why did you remove it and accepted another answer. I would be delightful to know if there is any particular reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `OR` instead of `AND`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NAME= 'Bob' OR NAME= 'John';
```

A `NAME` can't be `Bob` and `John` at same time, but `Bob` or `John`

Comment: oh, What I thought was, because I want both names to appear in the table, so I thought I want to use AND. but I see what you mean.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: @Seeker If it is not related with this question, you'd better ask another question.

Comment: The question, I think its bit silly, but its related to SQL, it will properly get down vote because I don'y really know how to describe it in better words, so I was thinking can you help me with it in the discussion section?

Comment: @Seeker You could search on this site first, because most sql questions has been asked already.

Answer (score 3):

The second query returns records in which `Name="Bob"` and `Name="John"` which will always be null.
You can try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NAME= 'Bob' OR NAME= 'John';
```

It will return records in which Name is Bob **OR** John.

The result will be:

```
DATA                NAME    MESSAGE                         TIMEZONE
01/03/2014 10:27    Bob     What time do you want to meet?  London
18/02/2014 02:43    John    What time is it in London?      New york
14/02/2014 00:50    Bob     Meeting today?                  London
```

See result in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/587c7b/19)

Read more about  [Logical Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189773.aspx).

**EDIT:**

For the second question, use this query:

```
SELECT name,message 
FROM table1
WHERE ROUND ((CHAR_LENGTH(message)
            - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE ( message, "out", "") ) 
            )/CHAR_LENGTH("out")) =1
```

It select records in which `message` contains `"out"` only once.

See example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d3f0/13)

See how the query works [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d3f0/24).

Comment: can I ask you one more question?

Comment: if you don't mind, can we take it to discussion section?

Comment: Sure.. If the question is simpler, you can update the question itself.

Comment: it might be a silly question and might get down vote

Comment: Doesn't matter.. Just add it to the question.. We are glad to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49347/discussion-between-raging-bull-and-seeker)

Answer (score 2):

Another way besides using `OR` is just to just to use `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NAME IN ('Bob', 'John');
```

Comment: hi, peeskillet, thanks for the post, you know my second question, do you understand it?

Comment: What is `message`? Is it a column in the result set?

Comment: yes, so you see there is the heading message and everything under that are messages sent from people.

Answer (score 2):

one thing is logically incorrect.
You are using

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NAME= 'Bob' AND NAME= 'John';
```

But, the name field can't be 'Bob' AND 'John' at the same time.
It could be 'Bob' OR 'John'

Probably, you want to do this thing. If I'm not wrong

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NAME= 'Bob' OR NAME= 'John';
```

Otherwise, use this thing

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NAME IN ('Bob', 'John');
```

Comment: Hi, muaaz thanks for the answer! but I have already found the answer. I will give +1 for your effort :) thanks once again.